# React native Maps not working in Production

Tags: android, react-native, expo, eas

I have implemented maps in react native by following the expo documentation but still whatever I do they dont work when I build my APK

During dev when there were no restrictions on API key the maps api was working fine but after building the apk the app always crashes then I followed these docs https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/map-view/ by downloading the service.json file and copying the api key in app.json after putting android app restriction by copying SHA-1 key from eas still always receive this error

```
{"error_message": "This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key. Request received from IP address 122.162.1X1.1XX, with empty referer", "html_attributions": [], "results": [], "status": "REQUEST_DENIED"}
```

I am able to see my map just not able to get the data from the places api enabled in android sdk

Please tell me what more data can I provide to rectify the problem